# Firestore, how to secure user input?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to have all my backend on Firestore.

Each time a user logs in, I wanted to update the `lastConnectionDate` in the `users` collection.

My issue is that all this data is sent via Javascript, so is unsafe. How can I be sure that a user won't cheat and say his lastConnectionDate was 50 years ago?

With a "classical" backend, I would simply add the current backend date without asking the user to provide it.

How could I secure this process with Firebase/Firestore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special [`FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` marker value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects) to set the server-side date in Firestore write operations.

In security rules there is a special [`request.time` variable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#time) that contains the current time.

By comparing these two in your security rules, you can validate that any value written is the same as the current time on the server.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Use a firebase function to set the lastConnectionDate. Maybe using the authentication triggers

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that. In this specific case Frank's answer fits better, but I will use your answer for other field type!